# Plot points with coordinates from txt-file

Tags: qgis-3, coordinates, plot

I'm using QGIS 3.12.

I have a list of coordinates in txt file, as follows

```
"longitude" "latitude"   
48.819056, 2.127009   
48.782213, 2.143340   
48.801580, 2.355238  
48.904471, 2.296038
```

How to plot this list of points on a layer in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution.

- Open menu *Layer -> add layer -> add delimited text layer*
- Select txt file in *File name*
- In *File Format* enable *Custom delimiters*: *Comma* and *Quote* `"`
- In *Geometry definition* select *Point coordinates*
- Choose *X field:* `latitude` *Y field:* `longitude`
- Add